# When to call HwndSource.RemoveHook()

Tags: c#, wpf

I am calling `HwndSource.AddHook()` to get the messages to be handled in my WPF window. I  wonder whether I need to call `HwndSource.RemoveHook()` when the window is destroyed - this window is not the MainWindow. If so, what is the right place for calling it (`Closing()`)?. It seems the Hooks are removed when the window is destroyed.

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

    HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
    source.AddHook(WndProc);
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (NativeMethods.UWM_SHOWMYAPP == msg)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

        this.Activate();
        handled = true;
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}

void StatusWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
    source.RemoveHook(WndProc);
}
```

Here while removing I am getting the `HwndSource` again. Is this okay? or should I keep the `source` object used for `Add()` and use it for `Remove()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If so, what is the right place for calling it (Closing())?

You could override the `OnClosed` method.

> Is this okay? or should I keep the source object used for `Add()` and use it for `Remove()`?

It's "okay" but it's unnecessary to call `PresentationSource.FromVisual` and cast the result more than once. This is probably how I would do it:

```
private HwndSource _source;
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

    _source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
    _source.AddHook(WndProc);
}

protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    _source.RemoveHook(WndProc);
    base.OnClosed(e);
}
```